# Saving methods in a dictionary and use those methods on key match.

Tags: c#

```
Public void test(){
   Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

Is it possible to save this method in a Dictionary, and call this method if Dicitionary contains the method's key value.

For example like this:

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable<method, string>();

string input = "hello"

foreach(Dictionary.entry t in table){
    if(input == t.Key){
        //Call the t.value method.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var methods = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
        //choose your poison:
        methods["M1"] = MethodOne; //method reference
        methods["M2"] = () => Console.WriteLine("Two"); //lambda expression
        methods["M3"] = delegate { Console.WriteLine("Three"); }; //anonymous method
        //call `em
        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            method.Value();
        }
        //or like tis
        methods["M1"]();
    }

    static void MethodOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("One");
    }
}
```

Comment: Done, I just needed 15 RS

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's pretty easy: just use the [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) delegate class:

> Encapsulates a method that has no parameters and does not return a value.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Action>();

dict.Add("hello", test);

var input = "hello";
dict[input]();
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/9GIdPV)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Func to reference your methods and then call them in the loop
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

And as @Lucas Trzesniewski answered your can use `Action` if your methods has no params